# Why is "wavefront" marked as incorrect?

Tags: word-usage

From Microsoft OneNote:

[image]

I googled it and it is used in many reputable sites:

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wavefront
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront

Comment: Spell-checkers do not dictate what is correct or incorrect. They alert you to *check the spelling* of a word they do not recognize, which will include any neologisms, jargon, rare or archaic words, and probably a majority of proper nouns. Never assume a spell-checker has caught all possible errors, and never assume errors as reported by a spell-checker are in fact errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because OneNote software, like most auto correction softwares, do not include some field-specific terms that otherwise resembles common misspellings.

You can remedy that by adding the word into your user dictionary by right clicking on it.

Comment: As a follow-up question, do you know why certain fields create new words like "wavefront" when it's perfectly fine separately?

Comment: I hope that the writers of the spell-checking software do not claim always that what it underlines is 'incorrect'. At most it draws attention to a point that you might want to think about. If you follow this site you will see that there is enormous scope for debate about what usages of English are actually 'incorrect', with some denying that that word has any meaning in the context of an ever-changing language.

Comment: In reply to NoName: I can only speculate. I think people do it specifically to indicate that they're communicating a professional term rather than a common concept. In computer science, the words "namespace" and "database" are such examples.

Comment: Oddly enough, Microsoft OneNote doesn't label database and namespace as incorrect.  The bias is real.

Comment: I also have suspicion that software people who built the system have a bias for software words, but at the same time I doubt they actually insert themselves into these decisions as oppose to just use an external corpus.